# Pyspark use groupBy as lookup - TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Tags: dataframe, group-by, pyspark, aggregate-functions

I want to add a new column to a pyspark dataframe (df1) that contains aggregated information from another dataframe (df2).

```
df1.show()

+----------------+
|   name         |
+----------------+
|     000097     |
|     000097     |
|     000098     |
+----------------+

df2.show()

+----------------+----------------+
|   name         |    id          |
+----------------+----------------+
|     000097     |     1          |
|     000097     |     2          |
|     000098     |     1          |
|     000098     |     2          |
|     000098     |     3          |
+----------------+----------------+
```

should result in

```
df1_new.show()

+----------------+----------------+
|   name         |    id_set      |
+----------------+----------------+
|     000097     |     [1,2]      |
|     000097     |     [1,2]      |
|     000098     |     [1,2,3]    |
+----------------+----------------+
```

to create a lookup I did:

```
lookup_set = df1.join(df2, ['name'], "left").groupBy('name').agg(collect_set("id").alias("id_set"))

lookup_set.show()

+----------------+----------------+
|   name         |    id_set      |
+----------------+----------------+
|     000097     |     [1,2]      |
|     000098     |     [1,2,3]    |
+----------------+----------------+
```

but when I try to access the lookup:

```
lookup_set["name"].show()
```

or

```
lookup_set["id_set"].where(lookup_set["name"] == "000097")
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You are treating Spark DataFrame as a Pandas DataFrame and that's causing the error.

If you want to display a single column, use the select and pass the column list you want to view

`lookup_set["name"].show()` would be 
`lookup_set.select("name").show()`

`lookup_set["id_set"].where(lookup_set["name"] == "000097")`

should be

`lookup_set.select("id_set").where(lookup_set["name"] == "000097").show()`